# Divisible subgroup of a nilpotent group and elements of finite-order

Tags: group-theory

I came across the following result today:

> Any divisible subgroup of a nilpotent group commutes with every
> element of finite order.

Any hints on how to prove this fact ?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be in the divisible subgroup $D$ and $y$ have finite order.

By induction on the class of the nilpotent group, we have $[x,y] \in Z(G)$.

If $y$ has order $n$, then there exists $t \in D$ with $t^n=x$, so $[x,y] = [t^n,y] = [t,y]^n = [t,y^n]=1$.